# How to Laravel relationship(hasMany) use limit or take for each records with pagination

Tags: php, laravel

I have comment List API with Pagination in laravel and I want a comment replay Array with every comment but only the last 3 comment replay.

```php
public function CommentReplay(){    
      return $this->hasMany('App\PostCommentReplies','comment_id','id')->orderBy('id','DESC');    
    }
```

And Query I have use

```php
PostComments::select('post_comments.*')->with(['users','CommentReplay'=> function ($query) {
    $query->select('post_comment_replies.*')
        ->orderBy('id','DESC')->take(3);
    }])->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
```

In this, I have been getting only the last 3 comments of all CommentReplay arrays. I have been not getting each comment's last 3 replies. I want each comment's to last 3 replies.

Anyone can help me on it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the trait: HasEagerLimit:

you can install it:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"
```

and then in your model:

```
class PostComments extends Model {
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;

public function CommentReplay(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommentReplay');
}

public function limitCommentReplay(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommentReplay')->latest()->limit(3);
}
}
```

and also in PostCommentReplies model:

```
class CommentReplay extends Model {
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}
```

now : when you load your relation ... it should return the result you desire:

```
PostComments::select('post_comments.*')->with(['users','limitCommentReplay'])->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: First, of all, thank you for giving me an answer. I will try this solution. Thank you very much.